# React JS: subdomain to a specific route path

Tags: reactjs, routes, subdomain

I have a path in my react website, `eg: abc.com/private/events`.

Instead of the actual path, i want to access it using `private.abc.com`

The rest of the pages and path would work with `abc.com`

I am currently using EC2 instance on Amazon, added a Route53 record set for the subdomain `private.abc.com`

Can you please let me know how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for already answered in the following SO questions

- [Subdomain in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658252/subdomain-in-react-router/38863509)
- [Create a subdomain like slack does e.g. : https://someteam.slack.com/ in REACT JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143565/create-a-subdomain-like-slack-does-e-g-https-someteam-slack-com-in-react-j)